# java Number Pairs Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I’ve been recently looking at a problem taken from a YouTube video I watched about a software developer interview for a position at Google. In the video the candidate was given an array of random numbers and asked how they would develop a program to count the total number pairs within the array, which give a sum of 8. So, for example, given the array {1,3,4,5,7}, the answer would be 2, (1,7) and (3,5). Before continuing to watch how the candidate solved this problem I decided to have a go myself. As you will see from my rather crude approach to this problem written in Java, I decided to use a nested for loop to iterate through each number combination and evaluate accordingly using an if statement. As I’m sure you will agree, the code is floored in many respects:

(a) In an attempt to avoid recursive pairs such as (1,7) and (7,1) I limited the iterations in the outer for loop to nums.length/2 . This actually works for limited number sets but, of course, fails when presented with number sets such as (0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,5,7).

(b) To avoid the number 4 being counted as a pair within the nested for loop, I added the conditional code nums[i] != nums[j]. Again, this fails when presented with number sets such as {1,3,4,4,5,7}, which contain legitimate pairs (4,4), which need to be added to the count.

As a relative newbie to programming, well….what can I say?...I gave it my best shot. But I am very eager to learn from more experience programmers and very interested to hear alternative ideas regarding how to solve problems such as this. Any thoughts on this….most appreciated.

```
package numberpairs;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class DisApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] nums = {4,2,6,1,5,7,3};

    Arrays.sort(nums);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));

    int count =0;
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length/2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<nums.length; j++){       
            if(nums[i]+nums[j]==8 && nums[i] != nums[j]){
                count++;                            
            }       
         }              
     }
    System.out.println(count);  
   }
}
```

Comment: Code Review questions should be posted on the code review Stackexchange. Not here.

Comment: You seem to have no error. Code Review Stack Exchange would be the right site for this

Comment: If you allow me, you should be able to fix your errors by yourself since you identified them yourself.

Comment: I agree with the others on the code review section. However as a small hint to solve the probem yourself: You already identified nums[i] != nums[j] to be a problem depending on whether on not the same number is contained multiple times. You do know the position in the array This should be enough for you to tell the 4s of your example apart.

Comment: outer loop goes from start to one before last, inner loop goes from one after actual value of outer loop through end...

Comment: OK...thanks for for your help guys and....I'll remember Code Review in future, didn't realise this before.

Answer (score 0):

The simple idea: for every number `i` of the input we should find the quantity of numbers equal to `8-i` that were earlier in the input. This can be implemented with a HashMap:

```
int S = 8;
int[] input = {1,3,4,5,7,7,4};
Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();

int answer = 0;
for (int i : input) {
    int j = S - i;
    if (m.containsKey(j)) {
        answer += m.get(j);
    }

    if (m.containsKey(i)) {
        m.put(i, m.get(i) + 1); 
    } else {
        m.put(i, 1);
    }
}
System.out.println(answer);
```

Runnable version: http://ideone.com/lqmuyL

This implementation has `O(n)` average-case time complexity and is [online algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks DAle, I'll have a look into this.